# Is there a way to format the warning and error messages that MSBuild logs?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I am using TFS Build to build my .net project.  The TFS build produces an output file that lists all the errors and warnings that were generated.  Is there a way (without implmenting a custom logger) to format the data that is output to this file (e.g. include full file path)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking, but you can crank up the verbosity on MSBuild to "Diagnostic" and you'll get a very rich set of data in the build log.